# Enumerating all strings in resx

Tags: .net, javascript, localization, internationalization, resx

We would like to enumerate all strings in a resource file in .NET (resx file). We want this to generate a javascript object containing all these key-value pairs. We do this now for satellite assemblies with code like this (this is VB.NET, but any example code is fine):

```
Dim rm As ResourceManager
rm = New ResourceManager([resource name], [your assembly])
Dim Rs As ResourceSet
Rs = rm.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, True, True)
For Each Kvp As DictionaryEntry In Rs
    [Write out Kvp.Key and Kvp.Value]
Next
```

However, we haven't found a way to do this for .resx files yet, sadly. How can we enumerate all localization strings in a resx file?

UPDATE:

Following Dennis Myren's comment and the ideas from [here](http://blechie.com/WPierce/archive/2007/08/01/Using-Resx-Files-with-a-ResourceManager.aspx), I built a ResXResourceManager. Now I can do the same with .resx files as I did with the embedded resources. Here is the code. Note that Microsoft made a needed constructor private, so I use reflection to access it. You need full trust when using this.

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Resources
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ResXResourceManager
    Inherits ResourceManager

    Public Sub New(ByVal BaseName As String, ByVal ResourceDir As String)
        Me.New(BaseName, ResourceDir, GetType(ResXResourceSet))
    End Sub

    Protected Sub New(ByVal BaseName As String, ByVal ResourceDir As String, ByVal UsingResourceSet As Type)
        Dim BaseType As Type = Me.GetType().BaseType
        Dim Flags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance
        Dim Constructor As ConstructorInfo = BaseType.GetConstructor(Flags, Nothing, New Type() { GetType(String), GetType(String), GetType(Type) }, Nothing)
        Constructor.Invoke(Me, Flags, Nothing, New Object() { BaseName, ResourceDir, UsingResourceSet }, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function GetResourceFileName(ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As String
        Dim FileName As String
        FileName = MyBase.GetResourceFileName(culture)
        If FileName IsNot Nothing AndAlso FileName.Length > 10 Then
            Return FileName.Substring(0, FileName.Length - 10) & ".resx"
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [System.Resources.ResXResourceReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx) (it's in System.Windows.Forms.dll)

Comment: Will that automatically choose the right file based on locale (like the ResourceManager) or do I have to write my own logic for finding the right file?

Comment: ResXResourceReader is more a low-level .resx XML file parser, than a resource manager.

Maybe possible to use System.Web.Compilation.ResourceExpressionBuilder directly, i haven't tried it though.

You would need something like ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager, but for .resx files..

Answer (score 1):

http://tonesdotnetblog.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/string-enumerations-and-resource-files-in-c/ has an alternative solution that involves putting attributes on enumerations that enable reading strings from resource files. This uses an alternative custom tool.